# how to get android device cpu model number via adb and python

Tags: python, android, adb

I want to get the phone's cpu code name via python, I tried to use `adb shell getprop` or `adb shell cat /proc/cpuinfo`, none of them can fit for all devices, the output didn't include the code name or even no any hardware info , is there any way to get the cpu code name for every phone?

I tried to use `adb shell getprop` or `adb shell cat /proc/cpuinfo` and I want to find a way to get cpu code name which fit all phone. is there any way to get code name like MSM8996 from the phone?